# is a field but is used like a type C#

Tags: c#

I have 2 projects (libraries)

For Ass1.cs  i have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ass1
{
    public class Class1
    {

        public void print()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }

    }
}
```

Ass2 is another library which contains a reference of Ass1. Here i am getting 
the error message for cd is a field but is used like a type ?

Ass2.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


/*  Class1 is in project Ass1 , import project Ass1 */
using Ass1;


    namespace Ass2
    {
        public class Class2

        {

            Class1 cd = new Class1();  /* gives error: is afield but is used like a type*/

            cd.print();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because your code is not inside a function

Comment: check my ans and tick as answer if it solved your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try to put your code inside a function or method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

/*  Class1 is in project Ass1 , import project Ass1 */
using Ass1;


namespace Ass2
{
    public class Class2

    {
        public void foo()
        {
           Class1 cd = new Class1();  /* gives error: is afield but is used like a type*/

           cd.print();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

put your code in a method or constructor

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Ass1;


namespace Ass2
{
    public class Class2

    {
       public Class2
       {
        Class1 cd = new Class1();  
        cd.print();
       }
    }
}
```